# Get All Of The Rows Like Input Text In TextBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008

i have a textbox and i want to find all of the words begin with the letter in textbox(for example a)

i know i should use

```
 "select * from tbl_search where Name like a% "
```

but it doesnt work for values in textbox.for example i wrote like this:

```
        cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from tbl_search where Name like @value%") 'it gives the runtime error :"Incorrect syntax near '%'."
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", TextBox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the command like this(need to add `+` between `@value` and `'%'`):

```
    cmd = New SqlCommand("select * from tbl_search where Name like @value + '%'")
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", TextBox1.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose your value in quotes:

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("select * fromt tbl_search where Name like ""@value%""");
```

VB.NET escapes double quotes to one quote, so that you can put a " character in your strings.

Comment: thanks but this doesnt work,runtime error : "Invalid column name '@value%'."

Comment: Ah, the old @value% problem. Missed that one. Try `"select * fromt tbl_search where Name like '@value' + '%'"`

Comment: You can't have quotes around @value.